# How to disable admob transparent interstitial ads in android?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

when admob displays transparent interstitial ad it cleared my ui text content

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by ruin?

Comment: explane more about your Question

Comment: when admob displays  transparent interstitial ad it cleared my ui text content

Comment: you can put a trace at the oncreateView, onPause and onResume method for the fragment. I suspect that when the ad get displayed, the view got paused. when the ad is closed, the view is recreated (this will reset your view to the default state).

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

This line is responsible for the "transparency" of the background advertising. [You can customize it by specifying its subject](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) or [use one of the standard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml). For example:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Panel"
```

Good luck!